# Any alternatives to reducing msg.value without resorting to refunds?

Tags: payable, gas-refund, msg.value

In my contract, users are required to deposit a specific amount of Wei. I want to prevent users from overpaying and need to decrease the value of msg.value.

Currently, I'm refunding the difference, but this incurs extra gas costs. Are there any alternatives to reducing msg.value without resorting to refunds?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not what you are looking for, but you can just revert the transaction if the value is too high. So something like `require(msg.value == 1e18, "wrong value");`.

Besides that there aren't really many options. You can't modify the value before it reaches your contract.

One, rather dumb, idea is that you could offer something more for the exceeding amount. Maybe more of whatever they're buying, or even something completely different.

Comment: Thank you, the dumb idea is not that dumb, I also have a function that gives the allowed limit, so you call the function, get the limit, then pay according to a limit.  OK then, refund it is, if there is no other way.... the reason why I think there is no other way is if you could increase the amount, you could make a malicious contract.